# test for models that points itself rspec rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm new doing unit test in Ruby on Rails, so I need some help in a test.

This is my model User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :created_by, foreign_key: :created_by_id, class_name: 'User'
end
```

I want to create a test to verify this association. I tried doing this on my user_spec.rb

```
describe 'should validates associations' do
  subject { User.new }
  it { should belong_to(subject.created_by) }
end
```

This is the error response

> Failures:
>
> 1) User  should validates associations should belong to 
>       Failure/Error: it { should belong_to(subject.created_by) }
>         Expected User to have a belongs_to association called  (no association > called )
>       # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in '

Comment: I would just add to the answers below that there's not a lot of value to testing this relationship, as there's no real logic involved. You are just adding some framework convenience methods. The tests won't do any harm, but won't really give you much either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ActiveRecord shoulda matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers#activerecord-matchers) do not require any object of the class to be instantiated for the tests to run. Here, you have initialised a new `User` instance as the subject, and have tried to pass that to the shoulda matcher to check the `belongs_to` association.
However, in order to check a `belongs_to` association on a model with a particular foreign key and class name, the following test can be used:

```
it { should belong_to(:created_by).with_foreign_key(:created_by_id).class_name('User') }
```

ActiveRecord matchers take lots of other options apart from the two mentioned above. These options are very well documented in the [Shoulda code on GitHub](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/association_matcher.rb)

Answer (score 0):

You give an instance to matcher but it waits for the reference name and the referenced class name. Your test should be like following.

```rb
it { should belong_to(:created_by).of_type(User) }
```